# FlatList not updating with React Hooks and Realm

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-hooks

I am writing a custom hook to use it with [realm-js](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/).

```js
export default function useRealmResultsHook<T>(query, args): Array<T> {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      function handleChange(newData: Array<T>) {
        // This does not update FlatList, but setData([...newData]) does
        setData(newData);
      }

      const dataQuery = args ? query(...args) : query();
      dataQuery.addListener(handleChange);
      return () => {
        dataQuery.removeAllListeners();
      };
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [query, ...args]
  );

  return data;
}
```

In my component:

```js
const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const data = useRealmResultsHook(getDataByType, [props.type]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{data.length}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

In the previous component, when doing `setData(newData)`, the `data.length` gets updated correctly inside the `Text`. However, the `FlatList` does not re-render, like the data did not change.

I used a HOC before and a render prop with same the behavior and it was working as expected. Am I doing something wrong? I'd like to avoid cloning data `setData([...newData]);` because that can be a big amount of it.

## Edit 1

### Repo to reproduce it

https://github.com/ferrannp/realm-react-native-hooks-stackoverflow

Comment: `FlatList` is a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), so it needs an entirely new array reference as `data` for it to re-render. I'm not sure how Realm works, but `newData` might be the same array but mutated? Try `console.log(newData === data);` inside `handleChange` and see what you get. If it's `true`, you must do `setData([...newData])` like you wrote in your comment. Note that `[...newData]` will only create a shallow copy of the array; all the elements inside of it will be untouched.

Comment: Piggybacking on the answer above if you give a key based on some hash of the data you can probably achieve the desired behaviour

Comment: @Tholle that's what I thought but `console.warn(data === newData);` returns `false`. So I don't really know why `FlatList` is not noticing it in this case... It is working ok with a `HOC` or a render prop.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. I know it will be difficult with a database involved, but maybe you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It would make it easier to investigate.

Comment: I created a repo to reproduce it https://github.com/ferrannp/realm-react-native-hooks-stackoverflow. Here is the whole main file https://github.com/ferrannp/realm-react-native-hooks-stackoverflow/blob/master/App.js. I didn't even have to use a `FlatList`, just trying to use a `Text` showing the length of the results.

Comment: I can't say for certain, [but I think Realm mutates the array](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#collection-notifications). It might be so that `console.log(newData === data);` gives `false` for the first press because the initial value is not the same array, but all following presses give `true`?

Comment: In that repo all clicks show `false`... But most likely something with Realm...

Answer (score 1):

The initial `data` variable and the `newData` arg in the handler are the links to the same collection. So they are equal and `setData(newData)` won’t trigger component’s re-render in this case.

It might be helpful to map Realm collection to the array of items’ ids. So, you will always have the new array in the React state and render will occur properly. It's also useful to check only deletions and insertions of the collection to avoid extra re-renders of the list. But in this case, you should also add listeners to the items.

```js
function useRealmResultsHook(collection) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      function handleChange(newCollection, changes) {
        if (changes.insertions.length > 0 || changes.deletions.length > 0) {
          setData(newCollection.map(item => item.id));
        }
      }

      collection.addListener(handleChange);
      return () => collection.removeListener(handleChange);
    },
    []
  );

  return data;
}
```